# Creating high performance animations in WPF

Tags: wpf, performance, pixel, shader, writeablebitmap

I'm in a situation that requires many animations with effects like transparency to be applied but when there are about 10 of them running, my application slows down to a grinding halt! :(

I also, tried implementing a particle like effect using a frame by frame manual animation using the CompositionTarget.Rendering event, which changed an Image's Source property at a given framerate. Again, this works fine for the first few instances of the particles on the screen, but when more and more get added I need it to stay performance wise, which is always a tough ask for any application

I was wondering if anyone has any experience using pixel shaders in WPF for animations, or perhaps custom writeablebitmap's for animations?

I basically need to palm off most of the animation processing to the GPU if possible...

Thanks for any help you can give!

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

If you want performance you should think about using XNA instead.
Then, you can add the XNA project into your WPF app

Comment: So, using XNA to process images and the like?